# React Native Navigation Auth Flow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, react-redux, react-navigation

I am building Simple Auth application React Navigation 6 and Redux. Issue is that React.createRef() don't work if I used it on non auth stack. In my Stack.Navigator Stacks are differentiated like this

```
<Stack.Navigator>
      {userToken === null ? (
        <>
         <Stack.Screen
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
            name="Main"
            component={Main}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
            name="SignIn"
            component={SignIn}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

My Ref file which I attach with NavigationContainer

```
import * as React from "react";


export const isMountedRef = React.createRef();
export const navigationRef = React.createRef();


export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current.navigate(name, params);
  if (isMountedRef.current && navigationRef.current) {
    navigationRef.current.navigate(name, params);
  } else {
  }
}
```

And attach Ref with NavigationContainer in App.js

```
 <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
     <Navigation />
 </NavigationContainer>
```

But issue is that if use Ref to navigate from Main to SignIn it works but if I try to navigate to Home after token is set. it gives me this error

The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator.

What am I missing here.

Comment: You don't need to navigate home screen when the token is not null that time automatic redirect to home screen.

Comment: Ahh... I found the issue. I was pushing the wrong array to dispatch that is why the reducer is not picking it. Thanks for the help.